# Remove lines by reading to the left of a specific character,':'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file of 100 lines that looks like this:

```
hsh:222
shhhshshs:2294
sjasda:2324
s_s:223
aaa:111
asdasd:1111
```

I want to remove all the lines that have more than 3 characters before the colon so the output would be:

```
hsh:222
s_s:223
aaa:111
```

How can I do this? I dont know how to read to the left before the colon. I'd assume its something like this:

```
for x in f:
    newline = x.strip()+.split(':')
    if len(newline.rstrip()) >= 3:
        f2.write(newline)
```

Comment: What's `newline = x.strip()+.split(':')` supposed to do? Look at the docs for those functions and call them properly (e.g., remove the `+`)

Comment: Can't you just check `if x[4] == ':' : f2.write(x)`

Comment: `grep -vE '^[^:]{4}' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You can call a method directly on the result of a method:

```
elements = x.strip().split(':')
```

This returns a list of two elements. To get the first element of the list, index it:

```
first = elements[0]
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
first = x.strip().split(':')[0]
```

Then carry on as usual. Keep in mind that you should write `x` to the output `if len(first) <= 3`, not `newline` or first.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of a list comprehension with filtering purposes. You can use the `find()` method of the `str` class to find the index of the colon in each word, and then slice the word from the beginning to the colon index.

```
list_ = ['hsh:222', 'shhhshshs:2294', 'sjasda:2324', 's_s:223', 'aaa:111', 'asdasd:1111']
output = [word for word in list_ if len(word[:word.find(':')]) <= 3]
# output content: ['hsh:222', 's_s:223', 'aaa:111']
```

---

For what I see, you want to write the content of the `output` list in a file (`f2`). You can do that as follows:

```
print(*output, file=f2, sep='\n')
```

Comment: You can also use the if statement as `if word[4] == ':'`

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed! That would be even cleaner. Thanks for pointing that out. @JoeFerndz

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some edits to my answer. You can try to get the same result using these two lines. Assumption is that each line has at least 2 characters.

```
with open("xyz.txt", "r") as f, open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        if x[3] == ':': f2.write(x)
```

The below code will resolve the assumption. This should be able to read the file irrespective of the length of each line.

```
import re
with open("xyz.txt", "r") as f, open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        if re.search('^...:',x): f2.write(x)
```

The reg expression will check if the value of x starts with any 3 characters followed by a colon (:). If it does, then the row is ready to be written into the file.

My input file in xyz.txt has the following records.

```
hsh:222
shhhshshs:2294
sjasda:2324
s_s:223
aaa:111
asdasd:1111
a:
```

The outut file in out.txt has the following records.

```
hsh:222
s_s:223
aaa:111
```

If you want to check for any string that is in the following pattern:
`:123`
`a:123`
`aa:123`
`aaa:123`

where `a` can be any char, then you can change the code as follows:

```
with open("xyz.txt", "r") as f, open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        if ':' in x[:3] : f2.write(x)
```

Here it will check for `:` in first 4 positions

You can write using the regex as follows:

```
import re
with open("xyz.txt", "r") as f, open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        if re.search('^.{0,3}:',x): f2.write(x)
```

If the input file is as follows:

```
hsh:222
shhhshshs:2294
sjasda:2324
s_s:223
aaa:111
asdasd:1111
a:
:1
```

The output will be as follows:

```
hsh:222
s_s:223
aaa:111
a:
:1
```

Comment: OP is allowing < 3 characters. Clever approach tho.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thanks for the note. I used the regex to search for : at 4th position. Please review and let me know if you. see any challenges. with this approach.  Appreciate your input and pushing me for a fool proof answer.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. First of all, the assumption in the first one is at least 4 characters, not 2. Second of all, you should be testing `if ':' in x[:3]`. The regex should be `^.{1,3}:`

Comment: if you use `re.match` you don't need the `^`

Comment: if I dont use ^ then it will match any string with `...:`. For example if the string is `abcd:123` then it will pick this as well.